# How to create custom module in magento with database table

Tags: magento

I have found lots of answers for this question. when i create new module follow that answer but system show error.

Link Url ::

http://www.phpzag.com/create-custom-module-with-custom-database-table/

Comment: You should read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

i want to correction some missing information from the answer link ::
http://www.phpzag.com/create-custom-module-with-custom-database-table/

1. /app/code/local///controllers/IndexController.php

class namespace_module_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action

2. /app/code/local///Helper/Data.php

class namespace_module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract